# How to open a Shared Folder on the File Explorer using Process.Start Method with userName and Password

Tags: c#

As title says I'm trying to open a Shared Folder on File Explorer using other credentials (I already did it without using userName and Password).

Here's what I tried:

```
Process prc = new Process();
prc.StartInfo.FileName = Folder; // <-- Calculated string, special characters correctly escaped.
prc.StartInfo.Domain = FolderDomain; // <-- String
prc.StartInfo.UserName = User; // <-- String
prc.StartInfo.Password = Password; // <-- SecureString
prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prc.Start();
```

That code send me to Catch on "prc.Start();" with the exception message "Access denied". The question is that the user I'm trying to log as does have permissions...

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: How is this related to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!**

I've made it work with:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\explorer.exe", @"\\Folder\", User, Password, UserDomain);
```

**User** and **UserDomain** are strings, **Password** is a SecureString.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559867/open-remote-shared-folder-with-credentials) and

[UNC Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132035/accessing-network-share-via-process-startpath-using-network-credential). Looks you need to use UNC path to get access of network shared folder

Comment: I already solved it with a simplest option, thanks anyways!